# Sony Bluetooth headphones are Paired and Connected, but there is no sound

Tags: headphones

Ref: Sony sony MDR-ZX770BN-Headphones

On my Computer (windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit, Under Manage Bluetooth Devices it shows that the MDR-ZX770BN headphones are Paired and Connected, but there is no sound.

When Headphone cable is connected to headphones, they work with sound.

What else can I do to get the MDR-ZX770BN to work, with sound?

Thanks ... Tony Brocato